# Al llenar un GridView marca error: No se encontró ningún campo o propiedad 'nombre'' en el origen de datos seleccionado

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo un GridView que lleno con la siguiente consulta en sql server:

```
SELECT Cliente, Articulo as Producto, sum(Convert(int,VPiezas)) as Piezas, 
sum(Convert(int,VKilos)) as Kilos, sum(Convert(int,VImporte)) as Importe
FROM SVenta
GROUP BY Cliente, Articulo
```

Lo muestro con:

```
 protected void MostrarGrid()
{
    cn.Open();
    DataTable dttr = new DataTable();
    OdbcCommand cmdd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT SlpCode FROM Vendedores WHERE SlpName = ?", cn);
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nombre", Request.QueryString["valor"]);
    OdbcDataAdapter dda = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmdd);
    dda.Fill(dttr);
    if (dttr.Rows.Count == 1)
    {
        DataRow fila = dttr.Rows[0];


        OdbcCommand cmda = new OdbcCommand("SELECT Cliente, Articulo as Producto, sum(Convert(int,VPiezas)) as Piezas, sum(Convert(int,VKilos)) as Kilos, sum(Convert(int,VImporte)) as Importe FROM SVenta WHERE SlpCode = ? and Fecha = ? GROUP BY Cliente, Articulo", cn);
        cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("codigo", Convert.ToString(fila["SlpCode"]));
        cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("fecha", DateTime.Parse(Fecha.Text));
        OdbcDataAdapter daa = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmda);
        daa.Fill(dta);
        var suma = dta.Compute("SUM(Piezas)", "").ToString();
        var sum = dta.Compute("SUM(Kilos)", "").ToString();
        var sumaa = dta.Compute("SUM(Importe)", "").ToString();
        GRILLA.DataSourceID = null;
        GRILLA.DataSource = dta;
        GRILLA.DataBind();

        cn.Close();
        TotPiezas.Text = suma;
        TotKilos.Text = sum;
        TotImporte.Text = sumaa;
    }


}
```

En **html**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GRILLA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" CssClass="auto-style5" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="555px" ShowFooter ="true" OnRowDataBound="GRILLA_RowDataBound1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Cliente" HeaderText="Cliente" SortExpression="Cliente" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Articulo" HeaderText="Producto" SortExpression="Articulo" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VPiezas" HeaderText="Piezas" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Piezas" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VKilos" HeaderText="Kilos" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Kilos" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VImporte" HeaderText="Importe" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Importe" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle Font-Size="Small" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Pero me marca error en:**

> No se encontró ningún campo o propiedad 'Articulo' en el origen de datos seleccionado. 
>   Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.Web.HttpException: No se encontró ningún campo o propiedad 'Articulo' en el origen de datos seleccionado.

**PILA:**

> [HttpException (0x80004005): No se encontró ningún campo o propiedad 'Articulo' en el origen de datos seleccionado.]
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.TryGetSimplePropertyValue(Object dataItem, Object& data) +2773814
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.GetValue(Control controlContainer) +209
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField.OnDataBindField(Object sender, EventArgs e) +58
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +84
>      System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +150
>      System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
>      System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() +185
>      System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) +160
>      System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() +17
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +167
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +3741
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +67
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +14
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +128
>      System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +34
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
>      VerDetalle.MostrarGrid() in c:\Users\becarios\source\repos\Alimenta_venta\Alimenta_venta\VerDetalle.aspx.cs:67
>      VerDetalle.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\becarios\source\repos\Alimenta_venta\Alimenta_venta\VerDetalle.aspx.cs:30
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según tu consulta, cambias el alias de los campos de la base de datos, donde por ejemplo utilizas **Articulo as Producto**, por lo debes llamar el campo como producto y ya no como articulo.

Por tal motivo te surge el error, la manera en la que lo puedes arreglar es cambiando los campos del DataField por el nombre de los alias, quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GRILLA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" CssClass="auto-style5" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="555px" ShowFooter ="true" OnRowDataBound="GRILLA_RowDataBound1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Cliente" HeaderText="Cliente" SortExpression="Cliente" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Producto" HeaderText="Producto" SortExpression="Articulo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Piezas" HeaderText="Piezas" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Piezas" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Kilos" HeaderText="Kilos" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Kilos" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Importe" HeaderText="Importe" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Importe" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle Font-Size="Small" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Yo había cambiado por como tenía las columnas en la base de datos pensando en que debía ser así, pero me equivoqué. Muchas gracias :)